# The input field doesn't show complete data

Tags: php, html

I need show the full data on `input` but it doen not show the full name.

```
$nombreC = $r['nombre_cliente'];    
    <legend><h4>CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE</h4></legend>
      <label for="nomCliente">Nombre del Cliente:</label>
      <input type="text" name="nomCliente" value = '.$nombreC.' />
    </legend>
```

I suppose it must show: `Claudia Nevarez` but the result is: Claudia.

Please, anyone can tell me how can I show the complete data of the value?

When I do `echo '$r['nombre_cliente']'` out the input, it shows the full name.

---

**UPDATED**

I forget something, I can show the full code, I read your comments, yes, I did put the `echo $r['nombre_cliente']` but it still doesn't work.

```
  echo '          
     <!--  CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE -->
  <fieldset id="infoCliente">
    <legend><h4>CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE</h4></legend>
      <label for="nomCliente">Nombre del Cliente:</label>
      <input type="text" name="nomCliente" value = "echo $r['nombre_cliente'];" />
</fieldset>
'
```

Comment: First is the problem that the input isn't long enough to show you the entire, or actually showing the shortened string. If the latter, what happens between the assignment and the concatenation. Since the code provided isn't valid I can only assume you've not posted everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
 echo '          
         <!--  CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE -->
      <fieldset id="infoCliente">
        <legend><h4>CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE</h4></legend>
          <label for="nomCliente">Nombre del Cliente:</label>
          <input type="text" name="nomCliente" value= "'.$r['nombre_cliente'].'" />
    </fieldset>

'
```

Or

```
$format =  '          
     <!--  CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE -->
  <fieldset id="infoCliente">
    <legend><h4>CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE</h4></legend>
      <label for="nomCliente">Nombre del Cliente:</label>
      <input type="text" name="nomCliente" value="%s" />
</fieldset>
';
echo  sprintf($format,$r['nombre_cliente']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

$nombreC = $r['nombre_cliente']; CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE Nombre del Cliente: " />

You are not putting $nombre variable under PHP tags.

Comment: Have you tried this: $nombreC = $r['nombre_cliente']; <legend><h4>CAMPOS DEL CLIENTE</h4></legend> <label for="nomCliente">Nombre del Cliente:</label> <input type="text" name="nomCliente" value = '<?PHP echo $nombreC;?>' /> </legend>

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments @amareetkumar. Edit your original post to add any new information.